# INSERT value using SELECT in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables: users with columns (id,username, password), and user_failed with columns (user_id, failed, time). is there any possible way i can insert into table user_failed by only using username? i try this code but it failed:

```
INSERT INTO `login_attempts`(`user_id`, `time`, `failed`) 
VALUES (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'pokemon','',3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your SQL query is incorrect for several reasons.

The following should work if I have interpreted your query correctly.

```
INSERT INTO `login_attempts`(`user_id`, `time`, `failed`)
SELECT id, '', 3 FROM users WHERE username = 'pokemon'
```

`INSERT`ing into a table from a `SELECT` does not require `VALUES ( ... )`. Here is an example of how you would use `VALUES ( ... )`:

```
INSERT INTO `login_attempts`(`user_id`, `time`, `failed`)
VALUES (1, '', 3)
```

Also, your sub query `SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'pokemon','',3` the `WHERE` clause is invalid. Specifically the `'',3` part which I assume is the values you wanted to insert for `time` and `failed`.

Comment: it's can't i get this error #1054 - Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list'

Comment: ah it's work, i just change user_id to id since in my users table it's id not user_id. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will work....you have to add plain parentheses before and after statements.

```html
INSERT INTO `login_attempts`(`user_id`, `time`, `failed`) VALUES ((SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'pokemon'),'',3)
```

Comment: *Curly brackets*? Plain parentheses you mean.